# Is a WebService call containing a Username and Password any less secure than logging into a site?

Tags: asp.net, security

We created a site for a customer a while back that has no site certificate/SSL.  It's just got a basic asp_net login system.

You can't buy anything from the site and it doesn't hold personal details - it just shows the stock and gives the users a telephone number where they can phone up and buy the stock.

One of our users has their own system and wants to grab bits of info via a WebService - we'd intended to just put a WebService with a WebMethod that took Username, Password and an ID and then passed some info back to their system.

One of the developers says this would make the system much less secure as the WebMethod call with the Username and Password is much less secure than the login system on the site.

Is this WebMethod call really any less secure than the login system on the site?

Comment: If it has no transport security (e.g., HTTPS/SSL), you're already hosed unless the "basic asp_net login system" is securely hashing at least the password before sending in the request header. "Much less secure" - A web service could require use of layers of protection that could include message encryption and digital signature; POSTing a form (or using Basic Auth), that's harder. Additional context into why the developer made that statement is needed to analyze his/her specific concern. It's not a given, though, and I would tend to think with the information given, it is possibly misinformed.

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on how you planned on accepting that password data.  You should make sure to enforce that they don't send a password plaintext over the wire. You can do this by having the following kind of pattern:

1. Client requests to authenticate
2. Server replies back with temporary public key. A temporary private key was generated and stored on the server that can expire after a short period (if it's not used).
3. Client encrypts password using public key
4. Client sends encrypted password and other data over the wire

In general, you should never send plain text passwords over the wire no matter what it is. Binary, soap, web service, http, whatever. If its sent, someone can sniff it.  All it takes is one good wireshark capture and all your data is compromised.

If are already doing the over the wire encryption then I don't see how it's that less secure.  It'd be better if you added some sort of handshake too so you know who is who, or if that's not something you can do to make sure to do rate limiting on requests if the IP source fails to send the correct token.  This is just like locking someone out your UI if they don't log in within the right amount of attempts.

Adding SSL is also a good idea because it will prevent man in the middle attacks.

I'm not a security expert but what I do know is that security is about layers.  Encrypt the traffic, never send plaintext, close ports, manage permissions, hash passwords, have a handshake, limit authentication attempts, lots of logs, etc.

Comment: Your pattern still leaves them vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks.  I would encourage using SSL in order to avoid this.

Comment: You're absolutley right. But like I mentioned, it's about layers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mix-mode authentication for the WebService file.

Please follow these steps:

- Right click on the webservice file
- Goto authentication
- Remove anonymous and click Basic windows authentication
- Add File name to web.config to make it accessible publicly

`<location path="webserice.svc">
     <system.web>
         <authorization>
             <allow users="*"/>
          </authorization>
      </system.web>
</location>`

- Create a user in the webserver using Administrative Tools
- Call the webservice and use the credentials of the user that you have created

`localhost.MyWebService myService = new localhost.MyWebService();

    System.Net.CredentialCache myCredentials = new System.Net.CredentialCache();
    NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password");
    myCredentials.Add(new Uri(myService.Url), "Basic", netCred);
    myService.Credentials = myCredentials;`

It would be good if you could use SSL when calling the Webservice